# python: format float string with maximum number of decimals

Tags: python, string, formatting, number-formatting

what I need is similar to `%.2f` but so that any `0` or `.` endings are deleted.
An example follows, on the left are the float numbers and on the right the desired formatting.

```
4525.0014436  ->   '4525'
4525.0091     ->   '4525.01'
4525.1036     ->   '4525.1'
4525.163465   ->   '4525.16'
4525.998      ->   '4526'
```

Is there a way to get this formatted in python? Or is it necessary to do it algorithmically?

Comment: The second example - why 4525.1 rather than 4525.09 ?

Answer (score 0):

found: just use rstrip('0.') after formatting with `%.2f`

for example:

```
>>> ("%10.2f" % 4567.001).rstrip('0.')
'   4567'
>>> ("%10.2f" % 4567.009).rstrip('0.')
'   4567.01'
>>> ("%10.2f" % 4567.1004).rstrip('0.')
'   4567.1'
```

Comment: This does not work as expected for `0` as it returns an empty string. Maybe make a special condition for `0` like: `'0' if f==0. else ('%10.2f' % f).rstrip('0.')`.
Otherwise nice solution.